# Magento - Notice: Undefined index: in ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php

Tags: php, magento

I have this error message a lot of times in my system.log.
I was looking at this message and it seems that is happening when you are going from the listing page to the product page and the size (m,xl,8,10) is OUT of STOCK.
Any idea how can I solve this configurable swatches error?? because is annoying in the system.log file. Thanks!!

```
2015-12-08T10:20:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: m  in /app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 145
2015-12-08T10:20:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: m  in /app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 151
2015-12-08T10:20:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: xl  in /app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 145
2015-12-08T10:20:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: xl  in /app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 151
2015-12-08T10:22:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 10  in /app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 145
2015-12-08T10:22:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 10  in /app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 151
```

Comment: any ideas please??? I need help!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add additional check if keys exist. Check my gist on github:
https://gist.github.com/Stasevi4/d991f541e117301e070cd7eb0d4ffffc